# how to use put method in map

Tags: visualforce, method

what is put method and what are its functions? can you teach me how to use put method in map or atleast links of sample codes for my reference? thanks in advance. newbie here. Thank you

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm

Comment: Please, try not to ask such questions. That's what manuals are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map class put() method is used to add data to the map on which it is called.

If you have a Map named as fooMap, you need to first initialize it with

```
fooMap = new Map<String, String>();
```

Then you can use method from Map class.
For Example,

```
fooMap.put('Key1', 'Value1');
```

will insert data in fooMap having Key1 as key and Value1 as value mapped to Key1.

All the keys in the map must be unique.
If you try use the same key again while inserting data in the map, the old value mapped to that key is replaced by the new value.

You can refer the [Map documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm) for more.

Answer (score 1):

```
String key = 'My Key';
String data = 'My Data';

Map<String,String> myMap = new Map<String,String>();
myMap.put(key,data);
```

- This is a very simple usage with Key and Value as String.
- You can extend this to any complex object structure by referring to the API here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm